# Where to define the login.flt as home page in alfresco-surf framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-surf

I have new bie to alfresco-surf framework and created one small application. I can access my page using `http://localhost:9090/surf/page?p=login` url but when i typed only `http://localhost:9090/surf` its showing

```
HTTP Status 404 - /surf/
```

Also I want to use this page for authentication and want to call my Java class to authenticate the user from database. but i don't know how to call my Java class and where to configure.

I create login.xml inside the WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\site-data\pages\login.xml
also create the template instance.

Please help I want to make it as my home page and want to call my custom java class for authentication and want success or failure to render home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.
In \webapps\surf\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\site-data\configurations there is a file named

```
default.site.configuration
```

In this file we have to mention the root page.